# Font-Color change in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML tag:

```
<div id="alert">Warning!!</div>​
```

And I want to give it an animation effect that changes its font color in a red - black infinite loop.

I tried using Webkit Color Transition Loop for background color with font-color:

```
#alert {font-color: #39f !important;}
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
      0% {font-color: #000;}
     50% {font-color: #990000;}
     100% {font-color: #FF0000;}

}
#alert {
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: colours;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}​
```

But it doesn't work.

Reference: http://snipplr.com/view/33728/
My Code: http://jsfiddle.net/LDRR7/9/

Comment: it's `color`, not `font-color`

Comment: font-color doesn't exist. Use color instead

Comment: and what's the deal with the first `!important` rule?

Comment: @ChristianVarga I'm guessing he copied it from the tutorial, would do better to ask the author (who happens to be anonymous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be using color as font-color attribute does not exist.

Also note that the tutorial you are using works in webkit browsers but does not work with firefox! So I have added the firefox prefix in.

See http://jsfiddle.net/LDRR7/21/

```
    #alert {color: #39f !important;}
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
     0% {color: #39f;}
 25% {color: #8bc5d1;}
 50% {color: #f8cb4a;}
 75% {color: #8bc5d1;}
100% {color: #39f;}

}
@-moz-keyframes colours {
      0% {color: #39f;}
 25% {color: #8bc5d1;}
 50% {color: #f8cb4a;}
 75% {color: #8bc5d1;}
100% {color: #39f;}

}

#alert {
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: colours;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: colours;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Comment: @KevinB It does work, it's just too slow. Check this example with more contrast and a smaller value for duration: http://jsfiddle.net/XBXaV/

Comment: Ooops. Looks like KevinB was partially correct, the original version, as well as my fork, does not fade back from the last color to the first, it just jumps back. See PitaJ's answer for the complete solution.

Comment: Very true, modified my full solution to stop the jumping :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `color`, not `font-color`.

Also, Your animation is wrong, it doesn't fade back to the original color, try this:

```
#alert {color: #39f !important;}
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
      0% {color: #39f;}
     25% {color: #8bc5d1;}
     50% {color: #f8cb4a;}
     75% {color: #8bc5d1;}
    100% {color: #39f;}

}
#alert {
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: colours;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}​
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/LDRR7/13/

Answer (score 0):

"font-color" isn't recognized by css. Try "color" instead and change the duration to like 1s to get the "flashy" effect.

Answer (score 0):

it easy to change the color using Css. Call the class and use **animation** ,
**-webkit-animation** attributes.These 2 attributes calls a kind of a function along with it u pass the time in seconds 
(Example: `animation: colorchange 50s;
          -webkit-animation: colorchange 50s;`

).
then u change the color inside the function ,in our example its called "colorchange".the way to use the fuction is to use `@keyframes colorchange` or `@-webkit-keyframes colorchange`.Simple as such.Another thing to note is the browser.For browser like chrome safari use @-webkit-keyframes colorchange and specify the color.U can c the Magic.
An clear example is give down as follow:

```
#Class .inner {
        -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out, width 0.2s ease-in-out;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        -moz-flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -moz-justify-content: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -moz-align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        background: #e74c3c;                                  /*circle circle*/
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 35em;
        height: 35em;
        padding: 4em;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em #FFF;
        cursor: default;

        animation: **colorchange** **50s**;
        -webkit-animation: **colorchange** **50s**;
    }

@keyframes colorchange
{
0%   {background: #e74c3c;}
15%  {background: violet;}
30%  {background:indigo;}
45%  {background: blue;}
60% {background: green;}
75% {background: orange;}
90% {background: purple;}
100% {background: #e74c3c;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome - necessary duplicate */
{
    0%   {background: #e74c3c;}
    15%  {background: violet;}
    30%  {background:indigo;}
    45%  {background: blue;}
    60% {background: green;}
    75% {background: orange;}
    90% {background: purple;}
    100% {background: #e74c3c;}
}
```

Hope its easy to understand ('-');

Answer (score 0):

```
#alert {color: #FF35CE !important; font-weight:700 ;animation:changecolor 5s;
-moz-animation:changecolor 5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:changecolor 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:changecolor 5s; /* Opera */
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes changecolor
{
0%   {color:red;}
25%  {color:yellow;}
50%  {color:blue;}
75% {color:green;}
100%   {color:red;}
}

@-moz-keyframes changecolor /* Firefox */
{
0%   {color:red;}
25%  {color:yellow;}
50%  {background:blue;}
75% {color:green;}
100%   {color:red;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes changecolor /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {color:red;}
25%  {color:yellow;}
50%  {color:blue;}
75% {color:green;}
100%   {color:red;}
}

@-o-keyframes changecolor /* Opera */
{
0%   {color:red;}
25%  {color:yellow;}
50%  {color:blue;}
75% {color:green;}
100%   {color:red;}
}
```